# Voxelize a Polygon Mesh

Tags: computational-geometry

I've implemented Marching Cube and Marching Tetrahedron algorithms to convert a voxel grid into a polygon mesh. Now I'm interested in doing the opposite, taking a polygon mesh and approximating it in a voxel grid.

I'm currently just working out my approach and curious if anyone has any guidelines. I can find the list of triangles that intersect any voxel cube fairly easily, but how do you convert the triangles into values held by the voxel vertices?

Steps

1. Determine which cubes are inside, outside, and on the border. Border is easy to determine, since if the a cube contains any triangles it is on the border.
2. From there I imagine I need to follow the triangle normals and project along the voxel grid to determine inside/outside. Mark all vertices that are completely surrounded by inside as 1 and all surrounded by outside as -1.
3. ?? This is the part i'm confused about. I need to take the triangles and somehow interpolate their values into vertex values. My guess is I need to find all points of the triangle that collide with the AABB of the voxel subunit or inside it and project it onto all subunit axes. From there I need to take those accumulated positions and figure out what the values should be based by setting the values between [-1,1] such that interpolation would most closely approximate the hull within the boundary unit. <--- this part is what i don't 100% understand.

Comment: You mean how to determine if a point in a voxel is outside or inside a mesh? Basically you can define a harmonic function inside the mesh that can be positive inside and negative outside the mesh.

Comment: Thanks @MauricioCeleLopezBelon, i know how to do that part. I don't know how to do the interpolation of the polygon to find the voxel points on the lattice. I don't have a functional definition of the model in this case. I want it to approximate arbitrary triangle mesh in this situation.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to associate scalars to the voxel vertices so that the faces of the mesh can be (approximately) reconstructed later ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust exactly, I want to work backwards from a polygon mesh to a voxel approximation. I'm unsure how to find the scalar values to associate to the vertices given the triangle lists.

Comment: @user2927848: for my understanding, these values only make sense for the voxels crossed by the surface, don't they ?

Comment: For triangles to appear that means the unit cube has values that are not all on the same side of a given threshold. If something is all inside or all outside then no triangles will be created within that unit cube.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, the values you should associate to the voxel corners are signed distances to the surface (positive outside, negative inside), so that the surface itself is at level zero.

If a voxel is cut by a single triangle, you can just assign the distance to the plane of the triangle. If there are several triangles that cross, the situation is more complex. You might consider the orthogonal projections of the corners onto the triangles and see to which triangle they belong.